# AngularJS custom directive - map isolate scope to new child scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I created a custom directive for bootstrap alerts. My alerts display fine (hard code and data bind). Based on the alert type, I want display a unique header into my alert message based on the returned scope values (success, info, warning, danger). Currently I'm passing the type into `<h1>` but I don't want those values, they need to be custom.

```
<!-- data binding example -->
<trux-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</trux-alert>

<!-- hard coded example -->
<trux-alert close="close" type="warning">This is an important warning message!</trux-alert>
```

Inside my directive, the scope is isolated using scope: '@' (one-way)

```
.directive('truxAlert', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            close: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<div class="alert" '+
                  'ng-class="[\'alert-\' + (type || \'warning\'), closeable ? \'alert-dismissible\' : null]" '+
                  'role="alert">'+
              '<button ng-show="closeable" '+
                       'type="button" class="close" '+
                       'ng-click="close({$event: $event})" '+
                       'data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'+
                  '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
                  '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
              '</button>'+
              '<h1>{{type}}</h1>'+
              '<div ng-transclude></div>'+
            '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
});
```

This would be easier if all my values were pulled through data binding, but I need to allow for manual hard coded option. I know with one-way isolated scopes '@' I can't change these values though DOM manipulation. I can't use '=' or '&' for two-way because the values are strings.

How do I solve for this problem?

Comment: You mean to say, you wanted to pass `type` value in hardcoded string like `type="Something"`?

Comment: Yes, the type can be hardcoded type="string". But there are only 4 accepted values.

Comment: So you could directly readout the  value from `attributes`, you don't need to bother about passing it in isolated scope..if it is not going to come dynamically

Comment: Or via data-binding, the preferred method, just depends on app.  Perhaps I need to only allow data bind option only. Then I could do {{alert.type}} and {{alert.heading}} from single data source array

Comment: The challenge is I'm trying to do both in single custom directive

Comment: but I can see you are only going to pass the value from `ng-repeat` then you could stay with `@`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is have one attribute for the control the open/closed state of the directive's alert and another attribute for the dismiss handler function.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('truxAlert', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            dismissHandler: '&',
            title: '@',
            open: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:
            '<div class="alert" ng-show="open" '+
                  'ng-class="[\'alert-\' + type]" '+
                  'role="type">'+
              '<button type="button" class="close" '+
                       'ng-click="truxClose($event)" '+
                       'data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'+
                  '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
                  '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
              '</button>'+
              '<h1>{{title+" "+type}}</h1>'+
              '<div ng-transclude></div>'+
            '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("truxAlert linking");
            if (!scope.type) { scope.type="warning" }
            scope.truxClose = function(event) {
                console.log("truxClose "+event);
                if (attrs.dismissHandler) {
                    scope.dismissHandler({$event: event});
                    return;
                }
                scope.open = false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The linking function of the directive determines if the `dismiss-handler` attribute exists and either invokes the dismiss handler or directly closes the alert.

The [DEMO PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hl3n9sS2ErTGs1CK7EgO?p=preview) show the directive being used both with an `ng-repeat` directive and in a standalone manner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, i don't understand you question.

You want to do so [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6juquysk/)?

```
<form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
  <span simple="{{val}}">{{val}} - value from data-binding </span>
  <br>
  <span simple="valueTwo">valueTwo - hard code value</span>
</form>
```

And js controller

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $rootScope, $alert) {
$scope.val = "valueOne";})
```

And js directive

```
.directive('simple', function() {
return {
  restrinct: 'A',
  scope: {
    simple: "@"
  },
  link: function(scope) {
    console.log(scope.simple, typeof(scope.simple));
  }
}})
```

**UPDATED**

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleOneController', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "valueOne";
    $scope.$on('pass.from.directive', function(event, value) {
      $scope.valFromDirective = value;
    });
  })
  .controller('ExampleTwoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "valueTwo";
    $scope.$on('pass.from.directive', function(event, value) {
      $scope.valFromDirective = value;
    });
  })
  .controller('ExampleThreeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = "valueThree";
    $scope.$on('pass.from.directive', function(event, value) {
      $scope.valFromDirective = value;
    });
  })
  .directive('simple', function($interval) {
    return {
      restrinct: 'A',
      scope: {
        simple: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        var i = 0;
        $interval(function() {
          i++;
          scope.$emit('pass.from.directive', scope.simple + i);
        }, 1000);

      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h3>
      ExampleOneController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <div simple="{{val}}">{{val}} - value from scope </div>
      <div>{{valFromDirective}} - value from directive </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h3>
      ExampleTwoController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <div simple="{{val}}">{{val}} - value from scope </div>
      <div>{{valFromDirective}} - value from directive </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleThreeController">
    <h3>
      ExampleThreeController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <div simple="{{val}}">{{val}} - value from scope </div>
      <div>{{valFromDirective}} - value from directive </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I've done a good job explaining my issue. There is no problem using data-bind and hard code value together. Based on the value passed from isolated scope, I need to create a new value within directive that I can populate in new VAR. Example: success = header1, info = header2, etc.

Comment: I think, I'm understand. Try `event` angular  `$emit` method. Pass your value from `$scope` like this `&scope.$emit ('value.pass',yourValue)` and then listen on your `$scope` like this `$scope.$on ('value.pass',function (event, value,){$scope[value.field].value.val})`.